# How to Automate web performance tools in React Application other than lighthouse

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse, gtmetrix, pingdom, lighthouse-ci

I am looking for a web performance tool that can be added to the localhost CI-CD Pipeline rather than manually entering the URL in PageSpeed Insights for performance check, I have heard about Pingdom but don't really know how to implement or add it to my localhost as there are not enough resources, I am searching for a tool that can be automated other than Lighthouse, looking for some API or SDK, I want to automate it on every significant change / commit to check that hasn't broken something

Answer (score 0):

you should check to react documentation for performance tools -

https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html

I this you got a solution to your question.

Comment: I am looking to improve performance using a tool not according to react documentation.